# Determine if a vertex is a part of a cycle in O(m+n) complexity

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal

I am trying to apply BFS to the following problem, but I'm not sure how to do it

> *Input*: directed graph $G$ defined by the array of adjacency lists with n vertices and m edges, and a vertex $v$ in $G$
>
> *Output*: $true$, if $v$ is a part of a cycle, $false$ otherwise

Can someone explain in pseudocode or in words how to do this?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: @Lola1984: what will happen if your remove that node? Think about it.

Answer (score 1):

Simply apply Strongly connected components algorithm , Kosaraju's algorithm has complexity $O(m+n)$. Now, read through the SCC components and check if $v$ is part of a component with size $\geq$ 2. The second step is $O(n)$. Actually, the second step can be interleaved with the first step to get your required complexity result.

A simpler algorithm may be just to to use DFS on the graph. Have a look at Cormen's Introduction to algorithms, chapter 22. Your exact problem is solved there using DFS.

Comment: I don't know this algorithm... and I can't use it, is there anything more simpler?

Comment: actually, this is a very simple algorithm, it applies BFS exactly twice, check it out here-:http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strongly-connected-components/

Comment: also, check my comment edit on using DFS in the answer.

Comment: @csTheoryBeginner just remove the node and check if the connected nodes to the removed node are connected via a different path. Suppose 'b' and 'c' are connected to deleted node 'a' so after a is removed we just need to check if there is a path between 'b' and 'c'. In the case 'a' is part of cycle then 'b' and 'c' will be connected otherwise no. Connection between 'b' and 'c' can be checked via dfs or bfs.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm:

1. Recursively keep removing degree 1 nodes from the graph.
2. Now, there are only either degree 0 nodes, or nodes with degree >= 2.
3. Now, check the degree of *v*. If its degree is 0, then *false*, otherwise *true*.

Comment: You should expand on how step 1 works in $O(n + m)$. This works like a BFS starting from all nodes with degree 1, and updating the degree of adjacent nodes while removing a node.